# Retrieve and Rank Python: What kind of "Answer Data" to pass to rank method?

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, pysolr, retrieve-and-rank

I'm accessing the Retreive-And-Rank service using Python. So far I've uploaded my configuration and documents and have trained my ranker on the relevance file. All that is left, I presume, is to pass some query results (from Solr?) into the "rank" method of my R-A-R object.

My question: What exactly are those results, and what form do they come in? And how do I access them?

Right now I am accessing the PySolr object using the get_pysolr_client() method, then searching a query and using the returned results:

```
answer_data = pysolr.search(query)
rrv1.rank(<my_ranker_id>, answer_data, top_answers=10)
```

I'm doing this because it's analogous to what IBM does in the rank() method in the [Java example](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/retrieve-and-rank/api/v1/#rank). But I'm getting the error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Results' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm getting this because PySolr returns a "Results" object.

What should I be passing instead to the rank() method to get it to work?

The Retrieve_and_Rank specification for the rank method is as follows, and I think that answer_data is supposed to be a "file-like" object:

```
def rank(self, ranker_id, answer_data, top_answers=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to call pysolr's `_send_request` method:

```
results = pysolr._send_request("GET", path="/fcselect?q=%s&ranker_id=%s&wt=json" %
                              (query_string, ranker_id))
for doc in json.loads(results)["response"]["docs"]:
    print doc
```

Thanks to rishavc on [dW Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/288779/retrieve-and-rank-python-what-kind-of-answer-data.html) for this.